# What's --- in grub.cfg cmdline mean in ubuntu installer iso?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, iso

This is a snippet found in boot/grub/grub.cfg Ubuntu 22.04 LTS iso.

```
menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

What does the `---` mean?

Why `linux` and `initrd` command works on UEFI system in this file? Doesn't it should be `linuxefi` and `initrdefi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the --- mean?

This is a convention from *debian-installer* (*d-i*).  As [documented in the Debian Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/apbs02.en.html)

> A “---” in the boot options has special meaning. Kernel parameters that appear after the last “---” may be copied into the bootloader configuration for the installed system...

Ubuntu installers are now mostly based on *subiquity* instead of *debian-installer*.  The convention was copied over though into *curtin* (which *subiquity* uses).  I do not see it documented, but found [this curtin source code comment](https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/d5f5dde574aca60935fc9e1acf9cb669e24f22de/curtin/commands/install_grub.py#L142)

> ```
> # return a string to append to installed systems boot parameters
> # it may include a '--' after a '---'
> # see LP: 1402042 for some history here.
> # this is similar to 'user-params' from d-i
> ```

Both *debian-installer* and *curtin* update the file `/etc/default/grub` on the installed system.  For example, using the kernel arguments `--- loglevel=7`

*debian-installer* will configure the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="loglevel=7"
```

and *curtin* will configure the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=7"
```

**Links**

- [Launchpad bug 1402042 mentioned in curtin comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1402042)
- [How can I add a kernel argument to a debian preseed file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1055649/how-can-i-add-a-kernel-argument-to-a-debian-preseed-file)
- [user-params source code](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer-utils/-/blob/76e752b7c7f9ad7e052a0eeddcb4ac6c9c67b344/user-params)
- [debian-installer package grub-installer source code](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/grub-installer/-/blob/90dd26631f534d4710cee80cd765ec36a3df7821/grub-installer#L438)

---

---

---

---

> Why linux and initrd command works on UEFI system in this file? Doesn't it should be linuxefi and initrdefi?

No. As far as I can tell `linuxefi` and `initrdefi` are more popular in RedHat based systems where grub was initially patched to add the commands.  The patch appears to have been copied to Debian (and Ubuntu) and the commands are available, but are not required for UEFI systems.

From the [help-grub mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2016-08/msg00014.html)

> linuxefi is not inclluded in upstream GRUB2, it is carried as
> distribution specific patch.

**notes**

- This may be [the current Fedora patch](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/grub2/blob/rawhide/f/0004-Add-support-for-Linux-EFI-stub-loading.patch#_803).
- It does look like [Debian included the Fedora patch](https://salsa.debian.org/grub-team/grub/-/commits/141cf59c76f7f42357875bfe128e47cfb8d9c922/debian/patches/linuxefi.patch) for a while but deleted it recently.
- Ubuntu [grub2 changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+changelog) indicates it may have had different variations of the Debian patch.