# Cloud-init: how to get kernel parameters into the grub config files during autoinstall on 22.04?

Tags: server, grub2, cloud-init, kubernetes, autoinstall

I proceed struggling my way through the cloud-init and it's documentation. One of my current challenges is getting the cgroups flags for the kernel into the grub configs.

The ultimate goal is to get GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0" in order to install k3s (v1.24) on 22.04

I tried various options - write_files, echo at the runcmd, tried even tried to copy over the grub.cfg also at the runcmd stage. Nothing worked for me so far. I use LXD instead of building an ISO each time. Looks like cloud-init works a bit differently but don't think there's significant difference at this point. So sometimes cloud-init just crashes. When it doesn't, it just ignores my stuff from the user-data and goes for defaults. Any ideas how to get it working or at list to figure out how to debug cloud-init properly? The logs are quite cryptic for me so far.

Comment: This question appears to be confusing cloud-init with subiquity / autoinstall. Cloud-init will ignore autoinstall configurations because it knows nothing about autoinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Using *autoinstall* with 22.04 my suggestion is also to use `late-commands`.  This is the snippet I would use.  It avoids modifying the primary file and appends your kernel arguments to any other `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` arguments.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      cat <<'EOF' > /target/etc/default/grub.d/40my.cfg
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
      EOF
      curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub
```

---

---

Another possible method that might work is `debconf-selections`.  I have not tested this, but I think the autoinstall file would look like this snippet.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  debconf-selections: |
    grub-pc grub2/linux_cmdline_default string cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

---

---

Another possible method is to boot the installer with the kernel arguments

```
--- cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

The [triple-dash argument has special meaning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464396/whats-in-grub-cfg-cmdline-mean-in-ubuntu-installer-iso/1485610#1485610) and the arguments after it will be added to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a custom ISO that includes a `user-data` file to allow an autoinstall installation on bare metal or a VM, then you can't test it with LXD. Simply stated, a LXD container starts from a .img file and not an ISO. Thus, the resulting filesystem isn't installed using Subiquity, Casper, and Curtin. This is the reason why when testing using LXD you're not seeing the results that you expect.

Furthermore, since Subiquity isn't running to install the OS, the `autoinstall` config key in the `user-data` file is being ignored. This is also true with `late-commands` config key.

Finally, if you create a LXD container, and look at the contents of `/etc/default/` directory, you'll notice that `/etc/default/grub` file is missing. That's because it's not really necessary and all default values are being used.

---

If you want to continue with a custom ISO using Cubic to include your `user-data` file for an autoinstall installation on bare metal or a VM, then this is rather straight forward.

The necessary steps:

- Create a custom `user-data` file
- Run Cubic

  - Add your `user-data` file and a blank `meta-data` file.
  - Edit `grub.cfg`
  - Generate ISO
- Install custom ISO on bare metal or a VM

---

## Create custom `user-data` file

To add a custom `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to your grub file, you can use `late-commands` config key in your `user-data` file.

```
  late-commands:
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"/' /etc/default/grub
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub
```

This tells Curtin to run two commands in the final stages of the installation process:

1. `sed`

   - to edit `/etc/default/grub` where it simply replaces `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"`
2. `update-grub`

   - to update your grub config

The following `user-data` file is a functioning file that I'll use in the next step with Cubic. This autoinstall will create a default user of `ubuntu` with password of `ubuntu`. Change accordingly.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: $6$5lpwCLsKLEzMkSJc$keOAhA6aO/5RocGThmhVA7LSNuW911Rx5HHXFEa75oGK20cEdAAgn14H5f5nGeq6QgcSyLPrWcg1.JvjXbhrN/
    realname: Ubuntu User
    username: ubuntu
  late-commands:
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"/' /etc/default/grub
  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub
```

## Run Cubic

1. Select your working directory
   [image]
2. Select your ISO. I'm using *ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso*
   [image]
3. Click *Next* to continue
   [image]
4. On the next page, select the *Preseed* tab and upload your custom `user-data` file and a blank `meta-data` file to the *preseed* directory
   [image]
5. Select the *Boot* tab and edit the `grub.cfg` file as follows:
   [image]

   You are specifically changing the 10th line to the following. Take note of the directory name where we placed the `user-data` and `meta-data` files. It is */cdrom/preseed/*, which is what was already created in Cubic.

   ```
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/preseed/ ---
   ```

   Here is the entire `grub.cfg` file:

   ```
    set timeout=30

    loadfont unicode

    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

    menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/preseed/ ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
    }
    menuentry "Ubuntu Server with the HWE kernel" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
    }
    grub_platform
    if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
        exit 1
    }
    menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
        fwsetup
    }
    else
    menuentry 'Test memory' {
        linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
    }
    fi
   ```
6. Click *Next* to come to the following page. Click *Generate* to create your custom ISO.
   [image]
7. When complete, you'll see this page
   [image]

## Install in VirtualBox

Installing this custom ISO to a VM in VirtualBox is pretty easy, and I won't outline the steps here. But once installed, you can check the contents of `/etc/default/grub` and you'll see that the file was correctly updated:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Thank you, @mpboden!

However, that's exactly how I failed. I just used runcmd instead of late-commands.

First created an LXD VM with your config as user-data. Cloud-init didn't create a new user nor did it alter the /etc/default/grub. Same goes for other LXD tests. Looks like LXD disables autoinstall.

Then, packed an ISO with Cubic and it crashed.

Ideas/questions:
- what's the difference between LXD and a regular autoinstall?
- could this be a Cubic issue?
- any idea how to debug cloud-init? Didn't find much in the logs. Maybe that's not the right place to look?

Comment: @Boris Please update your question with your full `user-data` file. Also, add your steps to create the LXD instance, Cubic setup, etc. Finally, please explain and add any error/log messages when you say it crashed.

Comment: @Boris I've updated my answer to help explain a bit better and to specifically use Cubic.

Comment: Thank you, @mpboden!
Well, that's a 95% match with my Cubic workflow:
- I even copy-pasted your user-data file to keep the yaml indents
- the only minor difference is my grub.cfg syntax, but it works:
```sh
menuentry "Headless Ubuntu Server Installation" {
 set gfxpayload=keep
 linux /casper/vmlinuz "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/" debug autoinstall ---
 initrd /casper/initrd.gz 
}
```

Comment: @Boris So my answer solves your problem? If so, feel free to kindly click the checkmark next to it so that I and others know that this is the solution. If not, please let us know where you’re still having issues and we can continue helping.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! Got couple steps ahead (shortening to fit the char limit): 
```sh
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
~~~~~
  late-commands:
    - lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    - resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sed -i  ~~~grub stuff
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub    
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /opt/payload.sh
```
This should install a K3S cluster. Tried engaging it via a systemd first boot service. Works with a dummy but not with a payload so far

Comment: Btw, could you please explain how to mix autoinstall with cloud-init on Ubuntu 22.04? Can I engage cloud-init after the autoinstall script runs?
Cloud-init also lists an ansible module. Do you know if there's proper documentation/tutorial?

Comment: This is what I ended up with:
`
late-commands:
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 pci=realloc"/' /etc/default/grub
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub
`